# Getting javax.mail.MessagingException:Connection reset while trying to connect to MS exchange server using IMAP

Tags: jakarta-mail

I'm trying to connect to Microsoft Exchange server using Javamail. I have used IMAP protocol and port 443 is enabled to listen on exchange server side. I'm getting "javax.mail.MessagingException:Connection reset" error. I'm using javamail 1.4.7 Please help..

```
Properties prop = new Properties();

prop.setProperty("mail.imap.starttls.enable", "false");

// Use SSL
prop.setProperty("mail.imap.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
prop.setProperty("mail.imap.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

// Use port 443
prop.setProperty("mail.imap.port", "443");
prop.setProperty("mail.imap.socketFactory.port", "443");

prop.setProperty("mail.imaps.class", "com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore");

Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(prop);

Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
store.connect(hostname,username, password);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Port 443 is the https port, not the imaps port.

If you want to use the standard IMAP-over-SSL port, just use the "imaps" protocol and let JavaMail use the default port.

Also, see the JavaMail FAQ for some [common mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes) in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your suggestions..Yes indeed it was problem with the port. As suggested, I modified my code as below and it works fine now.

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
//Use SSL
prop.setProperty("mail.smtp.ssl.enable",true);
Session session = Session.getInstance(prop);
Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
store.connect(hostname,username, password);
```